# How to output certain characters and add characters in certain positions in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure where I went wrong, but I created a class called phone number that takes a parameter of ph. ph gets converted to a string. So, when 123456789 is inputted like a.PhoneNumber(123456789) it should input out  (123) 456-7890 and when a.area_code is called it should give #123, etc.

Why does none of my scan methods work correctly?

Can I use the split method to pull out only #123 from 1234567890?

```
   class PhoneNumber

  def initialize (ph)
    @ph = ph
    @ph.insert(0, '#')
    @ph.scan(/.{0,1}/).join('( ')
    @ph.scan(/.{3,4}/).join(')')
    @ph.scan(/.{3,5}/).join('- ')
  end
  def to_s
    @ph
  end
  def area_code
    @ph.split(0,2)
  end
end
print "Please enter the number: "
puts a = PhoneNumber.new(gets.strip)
puts a.area_code
```

Comment: First argument to split must be a `String` or `Regexp` in `@ph.split(0,2)`

Answer (score 1):

The scan methods don't work because the Regex you are using are not doing what I think you think it should be doing.
`.{0,1}` matches anything between 0 and 1 character. That's why they just return the match string iteratively

```
@ph.scan(/.{0,1}/) #=> "#1234567890"
@ph.scan(/.{3,4}/) #=> "#1234567890"
@ph.scan(/.{4,5}/) #=> "#1234567890"
```

One possible way to fix this is to use indexes to get split the `@ph` in three parts. Alternatively, you can also use something like this to split the number in groups

```
@ph.scan(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/) #=> [["123", "456", "7890"]]
```

First argument to `split` must be a String or Regexp in `@ph.split(0,2)`

You can define `area_code` something like this if the first char of `@ph` is `#`

```
def area_code
  @split[1,3]
end
```